# Can not load node.js script on openshif

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have a simple script called countries.js under routes folder in my application. It fails to start because this line in index.js

```
 var countries = require('./countries');
```

locally everything works ok. how do I load my own scripts in openshift? files structure :

```
-app-directory
|
\ public
|
\ views
|
\ routes
   |
   \ index.js
   |
   \ countries.js
|
\ package.json
|
\ server.js
```

any ideas?

Comment: What does your server.js look like - are you launching your application from there?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've ever used openshift. You might try adding the `.js` extension in your require statement. If that doesn't work and I was faced with your dilemma I would try the following, which should work on any platform, albeit it is a bit explicit.

```js
var path      = require('path'),
    countries = require(path.resolve(path.join('.','countries.js')));
```

If that still doesn't work I'd suggest you start asking your hosting provider questions.